# Insert a link into the navbar in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have some trouble with inserting a link into a navbar with `navbarPage` in shiny. I can put a link but the navbar looks weird. Does anyone know how to fix it ?

To produce an app with a link in the navbar :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(
      title="My App",
    tabPanel("tab1"),
    tabPanel("tab2"),
    tabPanel(a(href="http://stackoverflow.com", "stackoverflow"))),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```

With shiny_0.9.1

Thanks !

**EDIT :**
A colleague show me a workaround, it consist of puting the link we want in panel 3 into the headerof panel 2.

An app to demonstrate this and the solution from @
20050 8519 21102 26896 16937 for the link in the title's app :

```
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(
    title=HTML("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>"),
    tabPanel("tab1"),
    tabPanel(HTML("tab2</a></li><li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow"))
    ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working on a more recent version of Shiny for the left-hand site element of the NavBar, the title, with this:

```
corner_element = HTML(paste0('<a href=',shQuote(paste0("https://my.page.com/",page_name,"/")), '>', 'Foo', '</a>'))
navbarPage(corner_element, id="page", collapsable=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
# [...]
)
```

Comment: Indeed it works well for the left-hand element of the NavBar !

Comment: You probably want to set `windowTitle` in `navbarPage` when using this.

Answer (score 1):

With shiny 1.7.0 and bslib 0.3.0, it became easier to customize the navbar:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  nav("First tab"),
  nav("Second tab"),
  nav_item(a(href="http://stackoverflow.com", "stackoverflow")))
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(...){})
```